# pushing multiple variable values in buffer

Tags: c++, arduino, printf

```
    void char() {
    char buff[50];
    int l;
    int i = 0;
    i = sprintf(buff,a,b,c);
    for(i=0,i<=l,l++)
    serial.println(buff);
    }
```

I want to have a buffer that will be printed like #123#234#

```
a=123
b=234
```

is it the correct way to do that? I tried but I didn't get any output. Probably silly mistake.

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abc() {
    int a = 123;
    int b = 234;
    char buff[50];
    int l;
    int i = 0;
    l = sprintf(buff,"#%d#%d#",a,b);
    for(i=0;i<=l;l++);
    printf("%s", buff);
    //return buff;
    //serial.println(buff);
    }
int main() {
//char bhg = abc();
//printf("&d", bhg);
abc();
}
```

I tried with this.Working properly but taking time to give output. Can I make it fast? Probably it is trying to iterate through that char[50] for allocation.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you set `i=0` in your for loop after using it to get the return value of sprintf?
Personal recommendation: check if `sprintf` is failing.
EDIT: Woah wait, doesn't look like `l` is ever initialized... Make sure you set it to at least 1 (at least from what it looks like in the supplied code). Perhaps you meant to do `l = sprintf(buff,a,b,c);`?

Comment: You're not posting the actual code: `void char()` shouldn't compile.

Comment: @JamesKanze look t the edited part

Comment: @Greycon please look at the code in edit

Comment: Are you working on an Arduino? I ask because you are using Serial.println...

Comment: And are you writing pure C, or C++?

Comment: @Greycon yes, arduino code. the above edited code worked for me with your help. I didn't run in arduino though. tested in gcc compiler. hopefully it should work. actually I am getting values of two sensor that is a and b. and I wanted to push them in buffer in a preformatted way. and the seral write. So should it work?

Comment: @Greycon I am not using cpp (although i am a bit confused about arduino as it uses both characteristics of c and cpp)

Comment: Well, probably yes, but as others have said, I would avoid sprintf if possible. The Serial class in Arduino-land actually implements Print, so you can do Serial.print(a), and it will print it as a decimal number. As in, it will convert it to the ASCII representation of the number.

Comment: but if i want buffer then also print offers sprintf kind of things?

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you use sprintf. You need to use a format string. Like:

```
l = sprintf(buff,"#%d#%d#",a,b);
```

Also, you are assigning the returned length to i in your code, not l.

Comment: It is working man. Thanks a lot. Can you please look at my edited question and help me more?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I'm probably violating SO protocol here, but base on your comments, you can do:

```
a = 100;
b = 23;
Serial.print('#');
Serial.print(a);
Serial.print('#');
Serial.println(b);
```

This will send this string of characters to your serial port: "#100#23", and in what is probably the most efficient way possible.

Comment: in this case for further extension ie, if i want to send via ethernet or via xbee, i won't send it

Comment: Correct, but you can grab the Print class, and use it yourself. I do this for wrapping strings and automatically updating a CRC value before transmission. All you need to is implement Print, and override a single write() method. See http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Printclass

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `sprintf` (which is almost impossible to use safely).  Something like:

```
std::ostringstream buff;
buff << "#" << a << "#" << b << "#";
serial.println( buff.str().c_str() );
```

should be all you need.  (Although I'm not sure: what is `l` in your code, and why do you loop over it?)